# Как в Razor-разметке получить дополнительные поля авторизованного пользователя?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

`@User.Identity.Name` по сути выдает логин. А как получить тот же Age к примеру?

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public int Age{ get; set; }
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public string Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По умолчанию используются только `Name`.

Класс `SignInManager` регистрирует пользователей в вашем приложении. Этот класс использует `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>` для регистрации claim'ов. Чтобы добавить claim нужно реализовать свой `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`

```
public class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public AppClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
        , RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
        , IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
    : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    { }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

        if (user.Age > 0)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
                new Claim("age", user.Age.ToString())
            });
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

Далее регистрируем в классе `Startup` в методе `ConfigureServices` после добавления Identity.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

    ...
}
```

В представлении значение Age можно получить так:

```
@User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "age").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

Для удобства можно создать метод расширения:

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetAge(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("age");
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

И использовать в представлении так:

```
@User.Identity.GetAge();
```

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ!