# Как получить поле модели User внутри страницы Razor?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

Я использую asp.net core mvc с identity. Для user у меня такой класс:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

И мне бы хотелось получить Rates внутри razor страницы, как это можно сделать с полем Name (User.Identity.Name).

Comment: Посмотрите этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/732874/215651)

Comment: @Ruslan_K не получается создать объект Claim. В конструктор он принимает только строки, а на List<Rate> ругается